# Updating cloud composer (Airflow) package dependencies using CI/CD

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, python-poetry

Thanks for your help and sorry for the long post!

##### Context

I would like to ensure python dependencies are installed in the instance of Cloud Composer.
A developer will need to install a dependency and so they'll submit the code to Bitbucket including these, and a Bitbucket pipeline will manage the installation in the Cloud composer instance when deploying the changes.

To manage dependencies, we (have to) use `poetry` and, among other things, the deployment also syncs the DAG folder with a bucket, installs poetry, generates a `requirements.txt` file and **attempts** to update the PyPI packages of the composer using the gcloud CLI following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#gcloud_2)

This last step, installing dependencies, is what I'm having issues with.

##### Where I am now

Below just the part of the `bitbucket-pipeline.yaml` that is relevant below:

```
- /etc/poetry/bin/poetry export --without-hashes --format requirements.txt --output /tmp/requirements_tmp.txt
- sed "s/\"/'/g"  /tmp/requirements_tmp.txt >> /tmp/requirements.txt
- gcloud composer environments update ${COMPOSER_PROJECT_ID}-composer --location ${COMPOSER_LOCATION} --update-pypi-packages-from-file /tmp/requirements.txt
```

1. Installing `poetry` works fine.
2. The second step (`sed`) replaces double quotes for single, thinking that could be the error - however the same error persists whether I add this step or not. I also tried a different combination that adds spaces between library and version but with the same error message.
3. The 3rd command is the one making the pipeline fail.

Given the error message (below):

- The `requirements.txt` file is generated correctly (apparently). I have 8 errors, exactly for the dependencies I was trying to add. ([Documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#export)).

  - Also, I added `cat` the file to the pipeline to confirm (see below anyway).
  - Also, locally, I run `pip install -r requirements.txt`, with the contents of the output generated by poetry, it works fine.
- I don't think is a matter of permissions, I had permissions error before and that were solved.

##### I guess my questions are:

- Is `poetry` not generating a full PEP compliant `requirement.txt` file ? Is there any (other) transformation to the file that I should be doing ?

  - [PEP-508 – Dependency specification for Python Software Packages](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/)
  - [PEP 496 – Environment Markers](https://peps.python.org/pep-0496/)
- Should I just be having a completely different approach to get this done ?

##### Versions

|  | version |
| --- | --- |
| composer | composer-2.1.11-airflow-2.4.3 |
| airflow | 2.4.3 |
| python | 3.8.12 |
| poetry | 1.4.2 |

##### Outputs

###### requirements.txt file generated by poetry

Please note that after running the `sed` command it would successfully replace double quotes with single quotes.

```
colorama==0.4.6 ; python_full_version == "3.8.12" and sys_platform == "win32"
exceptiongroup==1.0.1 ; python_full_version == "3.8.12"
iniconfig==2.0.0 ; python_full_version == "3.8.12"
packaging==21.3 ; python_full_version == "3.8.12"
pluggy==1.0.0 ; python_full_version == "3.8.12"
pyparsing==3.0.9 ; python_full_version == "3.8.12"
pytest==7.3.1 ; python_full_version == "3.8.12"
tomli==2.0.1 ; python_full_version == "3.8.12"
```

###### Error message

```
gcloud composer environments update ${COMPOSER_PROJECT_ID}-composer --location ${COMPOSER_LOCATION} --update-pypi-packages-from-file /tmp/requirements.txt

ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.update) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Found 8 problems:
    1) Error validating PyPI package extras and version ==0.4.6 ; python_full_version == '3.8.12' and sys_platform == 'win32'. It must be provided as optional extras followed by an optional versionspec. For example, '>=1.10.3'. For details, see the grammars for 'extras' and 'versionspec' in PEP 508 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/).
    2) Error validating PyPI package extras and version ==1.0.1 ; python_full_version == '3.8.12'. It must be provided as optional extras followed by an optional versionspec. For example, '>=1.10.3'. For details, see the grammars for 'extras' and 'versionspec' in PEP 508 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/).
    3) Error validating PyPI package extras and version ==2.0.0 ; python_full_version == '3.8.12'. It must be provided as optional extras followed by an optional versionspec. For example, '>=1.10.3'. For details, see the grammars for 'extras' and 'versionspec' in PEP 508 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/).
    4) Error validating PyPI package extras and version ==21.3 ; python_full_version == '3.8.12'. It must be provided as optional extras followed by an optional versionspec. For example, '>=1.10.3'. For details, see the grammars for 'extras' and 'versionspec' in PEP 508 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/).
    5) Error validating PyPI package extras and version ==1.0.0 ; python_full_version == '3.8.12'. It must be provided as optional extras followed by an optional versionspec. For example, '>=1.10.3'. For details, see the grammars for 'extras' and 'versionspec' in PEP 508 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/).
    6) Error validating PyPI package extras and version ==3.0.9 ; python_full_version == '3.8.12'. It must be provided as optional extras followed by an optional versionspec. For example, '>=1.10.3'. For details, see the grammars for 'extras' and 'versionspec' in PEP 508 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/).
    7) Error validating PyPI package extras and version ==7.3.1 ; python_full_version == '3.8.12'. It must be provided as optional extras followed by an optional versionspec. For example, '>=1.10.3'. For details, see the grammars for 'extras' and 'versionspec' in PEP 508 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/).
    8) Error validating PyPI package extras and version ==2.0.1 ; python_full_version == '3.8.12'. It must be provided as optional extras followed by an optional versionspec. For example, '>=1.10.3'. For details, see the grammars for 'extras' and 'versionspec' in PEP 508 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/).
```

Comment: could you try loosening the version constraints for installed PyPI packages? ie. instead of specifying a version as ==0.4.6, could you specify it as >=0.4.6?

Comment: hi @SakshiGatyan thanks for your help. I actually tried that (I should have mentioned it in my details above). Unfortunatelly this didn't work either. I tested out multiple things from the Cloud console directly, but as far as I can see, it doesn't like anything after the semicolon `;`. It worked well with once I remove the `python_full_version` etc... my solution was then to write a snippet that edits the generated requirements.txt to only include {package}{version}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our discussion in the comments, this issue was resolved by editing the script by removing the part after `;` ie. `python_full_version` was removed from the requirement.txt

To automate this, a snippet that edits the generated `requirements.txt` to only include PyPI `<package><version>` was written.